# window.onload only running one function when I set it to two different functions

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am getting a problem with these two scripts I coded, it appears as though whichever script is on the bottom functions, so if I switch them around the one on bottom works. Please help. Code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
//Badge
var eSelect = document.getElementById('leftbadge');
        var yellowplate = document.getElementById('numberplateyellow');
        var whiteplate = document.getElementById('numberplatewhite');
        eSelect.onchange = function() {
            if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 0) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url("builder/yellow_bg.png")';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url("builder/white_bg.png")';
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'center';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '0';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'center';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '0';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 1) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_ENG.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_ENG.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 2) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_GB.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_GB.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 3) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_GB2.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_GB2.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 4) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_SCO.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_SCO.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 5) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_CYMRU.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_CYMRU.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }
        }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Font
        window.onload = function() {
        var eSelect = document.getElementById('font');
        var yellowplate = document.getElementById('numberplateyellow');
        var whiteplate = document.getElementById('numberplatewhite');
        eSelect.onchange = function() {
            if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 0) {
                yellowplate.style.fontFamily = 'JepsonCarRegular';
                whiteplate.style.fontFamily = 'JepsonCarRegular';
            } else {
                yellowplate.style.fontFamily = 'twotoneRegular';
                whiteplate.style.fontFamily = 'twotoneRegular';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

So in this example the font will change but the badges wont if I try there drop down

Comment: Why have 2 script sections?  You also have 2 window.onload functions.  Why not put the logic into 1 window.onload function in 1 script block?

Comment: I'm sure that you can improve on your question title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning 2 actions to the window.onload. The bottom one will always execute because that is the last one that is assigned to (and hence, it has overriden the previous function assignment).

You should look into merging the 2 onload actions into 1, a bit like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleBadges()
{
    //Badge
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('leftbadge');
    var yellowplate = document.getElementById('numberplateyellow');
    var whiteplate = document.getElementById('numberplatewhite');
    eSelect.onchange = function() 
    {
        if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 0) {
            yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url("builder/yellow_bg.png")';
            whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url("builder/white_bg.png")';
            yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'center';
            yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '0';
            whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'center';
            whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '0';
        }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 1) {
            yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_ENG.png)';
            whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_ENG.png)';
            //Align To Right and then add padding
            yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
        }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 2) {
            yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_GB.png)';
            whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_GB.png)';
            //Align To Right and then add padding
            yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
        }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 3) {
            yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_GB2.png)';
            whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_GB2.png)';
            //Align To Right and then add padding
            yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
        }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 4) {
            yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_SCO.png)';
            whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_SCO.png)';
            //Align To Right and then add padding
            yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
        }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 5) {
            yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_CYMRU.png)';
            whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_CYMRU.png)';
            //Align To Right and then add padding
            yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
            whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
        }
    }
}    
function handleFonts()
{
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('font');
    var yellowplate = document.getElementById('numberplateyellow');
    var whiteplate = document.getElementById('numberplatewhite');
    eSelect.onchange = function() {
        if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 0) {
            yellowplate.style.fontFamily = 'JepsonCarRegular';
            whiteplate.style.fontFamily = 'JepsonCarRegular';
        } else {
            yellowplate.style.fontFamily = 'twotoneRegular';
            whiteplate.style.fontFamily = 'twotoneRegular';
        }
    }
}
window.onload = function() 
{
    handleBadges()
    handleFonts()
}
</script>
```

Comment: But if later on, he needs to add another function to execute, he'll have to add it in that `window.onload = fun...` block. Won't `window.onload =` clear listeners added via `window.addEventListener();`? So if he starts using some external library that appends events that way, they won't work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use addEventListener. If I'm not mistaken, when you set window.onload, you replace whatever was there instead of add another listener for the onload event.

check this link out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
//Badge
var eSelect = document.getElementById('leftbadge');
        var yellowplate = document.getElementById('numberplateyellow');
        var whiteplate = document.getElementById('numberplatewhite');
        eSelect.onchange = function() {
            if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 0) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url("builder/yellow_bg.png")';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url("builder/white_bg.png")';
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'center';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '0';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'center';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '0';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 1) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_ENG.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_ENG.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 2) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_GB.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_GB.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 3) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_GB2.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_GB2.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 4) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_SCO.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_SCO.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }else if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 5) {
                yellowplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/yellow_bg_CYMRU.png)';
                whiteplate.style.backgroundImage = 'url(builder/white_bg_CYMRU.png)';
                //Align To Right and then add padding
                yellowplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                yellowplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
                whiteplate.style.textAlign = 'right';
                whiteplate.style.paddingRight = '10px';
            }
        }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Font
    window.addEventListener("load",function() {
        var eSelect = document.getElementById('font');
        var yellowplate = document.getElementById('numberplateyellow');
        var whiteplate = document.getElementById('numberplatewhite');
        eSelect.onchange = function() {
            if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 0) {
                yellowplate.style.fontFamily = 'JepsonCarRegular';
                whiteplate.style.fontFamily = 'JepsonCarRegular';
            } else {
                yellowplate.style.fontFamily = 'twotoneRegular';
                whiteplate.style.fontFamily = 'twotoneRegular';
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```